# Is there any benefit to importing a save, rather than simulating one?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I know that The Witcher 3 [allows me to 'simulate' a Witcher 2 save by allowing me to make various key decisions about what happened in the previous game.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220228/which-decisions-carry-over-from-the-first-two-games)

However, I *do* have some Witcher 2 save files lying around. Thing is, I don't remember for sure what choices are in them, and I feel like I'd benefit from making them fresh. Alternately, I could always double back and replay the final chapter of The Witcher 2, or just roll the dice on whatever save I have lying around.

Is there any benefit or change from using an import, rather than simply making the choices in-game in The Witcher 3? For example, do any items carry over or NPC's or other changes that are not brought over based on the Q&A session?

Answer (score 11):

According to CD Projekt RED, no Items or Equipment carries over from The Witcher 2 save file.

Only decisions carry over.

Because they made the games for the consoles and they don't have previous save files they allowed for the user to choose the decisions of past games.

**So basically there are no differences from importing the save and simulating one by choosing the decisions.**

Since you don't quite remember what you did in those Witcher 2 save files I would recommend to you the simulation of one by choosing the decisions in-game, and you will be more aware of the decisions in-game.

No, not all decisions carry over. Only really important ones for the story. The decisions that are made in the Q&A session are:

- Did you kill Aryan?
- Did you choose Yorveth or Roche?
- If you picked Yorveth you'll 2 choices: did you save Triss or break the curse of Saskia? If you picked Roche did you save Triss or help him save Anais?
- Did you help Sile in the Megascope or not?
- Did you let Letho go or not?

**Source:** [vg247](http://www.vg247.com/2015/05/15/this-is-how-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt-brings-over-your-witcher-2-decisions/)

There are some decisions that you make in the Witcher 2 for example: (SPOILER ALERT)

> If you killed King Henselt

This decision is not mentioned in the Q&A Session and there are other decisions that are not mentioned.

Comment: Are there any *decisions* that carry over that are not part of the little Q&A session?

Comment: added some more information @LessPop_MoreFizz

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - As far as I know, only the tattoo

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz -- one more: if in Flotsam you [joined the alchemists' experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsA4ob3ANjA), then there will be a note in the Oxenfurt Academy revealing details about the potion you drank. It's supposed to reverse Geralt's infertility.

Answer (score 9):

The tattoo you get from getting drunk with Ves and the blue stripes in the witcher 2, remains in the witcher 3 if you import your save file.

Answer (score 2):

No, unlike the import from Witcher 1 to Witcher 2, importing an actual save file does not grant any tangible benefits (e.g. gold, equipment, etc.).

I've tested this by briefly playing through with and without a save. Others have also observed similarly and can probably corroborate: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/699808-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/71826024

Answer (score 0):

There's a wiki page that's says some steel swords and silver swords, 1 armor, and a percentage of your ores transfer over. Haven't tested to see if that's true or not, but a lot of people are saying there are no benedits

Answer (score 0):

There are some things such as Henselt's fate that will be appearing only if imported. There's also a mission called Hung Over that will get you a tattoo in The Witcher 2. If you import, Geralt will have a lousy tattoo on his neck.