# When do you get asked the questions in order to simulate a Witcher 2 savegame?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I started a game with what I think was an option to simulate a Witcher 2 save game. I expected to answer a bunch of questions of what I did, yet as of yet nothing happened. How does this option work and when in-game will I be able to simulate the Witcher 2 savegame?

I am not interested as to what the difference are in between importing or simulating a save game, I just want to make sure I did not mistakenly start a new game without the ability to simulate the Witcher 2 savegame at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any benefit to importing a save, rather than simulating one?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220534/is-there-any-benefit-to-importing-a-save-rather-than-simulating-one)

Comment: @Nitro.de Nope. It's not about benefits, but more in "When do you get asked the question in order to simulate a Witcher 2 savegame?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you chose for the option to simulate the Witcher 2 save you will be asked some questions by an NPC right after the prologue. More specifically,

> this happens right after you killed the griffin and decide to go to Yennefer. You meet her, she takes you with her and you meet a king, then during a shaving scene you get asked some questions about the witcher 2 decisions.

These questions are (Spoiler for Witcher 2 - Assassin of Kings):

> - Did you kill Aryan?
>  - Did you choose Yorveth or Roche?
>  - If you picked Yorveth you'll 2 choices: did you save Triss or break
>    the curse of Saskia? If you picked Roche did you save Triss or help
>    him save Anais?
>  - Did you help Sile in the Megascope or not?
>  - Did you let Letho go or not?

Comment: Yennefer, please.

Comment: Thx didn't notice that, answered from my phone and it autocorrected

Comment: @HaroldCavendish You could have edited, you know ;)

Comment: @k0pernikus I should have. Sorry, I didn't mean to be the Comic Book Guy who criticises for minor errors – my reaction was a weird blend of having just seen Conan's review of TW3 in which he kept calling her Jennifer for a joke and recalling a ‘gooby pls’ comic strip. Therefore it was actually a humorous reference which only I could understand, which in turn wasn't very humorous at all. Anyway… :D

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to simulate a save you will be asked some questions about the previous game **when being shaved in the Royal Palace in Vizima**.

I've already covered the things they ask and don't ask in this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220534/is-there-any-benefit-to-importing-a-save-rather-than-simulating-one/220768#220768).

Answer (score 1):

you get asked the questions after the prologue, when getting shaved

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? For example, what do you get asked? When does this prompt occur "When getting shaved" is a bit vague

Comment: @Ben But it would be spoilery then. After the prologue should be enough info.

Comment: @lyrion but doesn't really answer the original question, surely, without enough detail to reassure.

Comment: @Jeeva I read the question as When do I get to simulate the witcher 2 savegame?: After the prologue

Comment: You can use the spoiler tag >! for spoilers

Comment: @Lyrion - Sure, but it's easy for us, because we know when the shaving happens. By prologue, do you mean "the dream sequence"? The bit after that? The first big monster? I can't remember it ever telling you "Right, that's it." It's obvious, looking back, but hard to feel reassured if you don't know.